# How to call ruby value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby value that is referred to as `<%= @random_quote.quote %>` which outputs a string, and I would like to set this string equal to the javascript value in `document.getElementById("quoteArea").value =  "value"`. I have looked around here and found similar questions but none of them solve my problem. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are **using erb** for your views:

```
# your_view.html.erb
document.getElementById("quoteArea").value =  "<%= @random_quote.quote %>";
```

If you are **using HAML** for your views:

```
# your_view.html.haml
:javascript
  document.getElementById("quoteArea").value =  "#{@random_quote.quote}";
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some.js.erb in your assets pipeline and assign the value from there, not a very good approach but one way to go, or you can set the value in DOM( Document Object Model ) in certain element data and get the value from there. As follows an dummy example.

```
<div data-my_value="<%= @random_quote.quote %>"></div>
jQuery("[data-my_value]").data("my_value");
```

Some thing like that. Hope this helps you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If the element with the id `#quoteArea` is available in your view, you should be able to set it's value using the same erb code you referenced in your question.

If you do not have any control over the `#quoteArea` element, you can define a javascript variable in your page that you can then use later:

```
// In Your HTML View
<script>
  var quote = "<%= @random_quote.quote %>";
</script>

// In a JS File loaded after the variable assignment
document.getElementById("quoteArea").value = quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign that Ruby value to a JavaScript variable.

Something like:

```
var myVariable = "<%= @random_quote.quote %>";

document.getElementById("quoteArea").value = myVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a **file.js.erb**
The files are interpreted first by ruby then by js.

```
var jsVariable = "<%=ruby_variable%>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) If you need to send some data to your js files and you don't want to do this with long way through views and parsing.
This assigns values to variables that will be accessed through javascript

```
gon.variable_name = variable_value

# or new syntax
gon.push({
  :user_id => 1,
  :user_role => "admin"
})

gon.push(any_object) # any_object with respond_to? :each_pair
```

Then to access that variable in javascript do:

```
gon.variable_name
```

In the JS file.